# @font-face: in CSS isn't working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have the following in my css and the font won't change to what I want it to become.

```
body{
background-color:#a8a7a7;
color:#C50909;
font-family: main, Calibri;
text-align:center;
}    

@font-face{ 
font-family: main;
src: url('fonts/RegencieLight.ttf'); 
}
```

and my css properly links into my html because all of the other css aspects will still be applied. If anyone could help me that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: start with this: `font-family: "main"`. Is the fonts folder inside your css folder?

Answer (score 2):

You must provide a string as the font-family name like this

```
font-family: "main";
```

so that you can reference it in other places like this

```
font-family: "main", Calibri
```

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. the path is wrong or
2. depending on the browser and operating system it could not like the font format

Either way I recommend reading [Paul Irish's bullet proof @font-face syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) and using [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator/packager](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) The packager will take a font and create each format that a web client might need so it will work on all systems.

Comment: Hi thank you for that, I wasn't aware of all that but asides that I have narrowed down the problem to the path and found out my partner made the css files into a seperate folder I never realized it after so much fustration, anyways thanks for the help and useful information.